# Word files have been converted to Microsoft Office 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

All of a sudden my word files became Microsoft office 2010 files and since I do not own that subscription, I cannot open them anymore.  Not sure when or HOW this happened.

Comment: You mean your doc-files became docx? Every Office version from at least 2003 on can open those. You could open and resave them in the older format. In any case, they weren't converted on their own. As an educated guess, I'd assume you probably opened them in Wordpad instead of Word and then just automatically saved them to the new format.

Comment: Please clarify what happen exactly and explain what Office you do have access too

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it -  I downloaded an update which showed up as Microsoft office and caused my Word & excel starter not to work.  I created a restore point first in case it failed then found Microsoft office in my program list. It had a recent date in last modified column and I know I definitely didn't download it intentionally.  I then uninstalled it.  My files now have their Word & Excel icons back & I can open them through my Documents

Comment: Which specific update did you install?